# Explorer.exe in Winforms to Browse to a Network Folder

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, explorer

I have a C# winforms application that I am using.  I have a "browse output folder" button that takes the user to a specific path on a network drive for our local systems.

However, I have been getting these weird exceptions from Explorer.exe where it crashes for no particular reason with no real error message.  This occurs when the folder opens up properly and sits for a while, it will open a message saying that it "has stopped working" and asks me to close it.  This issue is very repeatable.

My best guess at the issue is that it is a network related problem.  The network has been known to be glitchy occasionally (goes up/down briefly fairly often).  Could this cause the problem?

[image: Explorer crash]

The code I use is (I do typically check that the folder path is valid):

```
string Path = "\\\\serverPath\\data\\My Folder\\";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Explorer.exe", Path);
```

**Basic question summary**: Am I making this call to Explorer.exe improperly / is there a better/safer way of doing this to avoid this problem?

EDIT: OR is as I expected and is just a windows bug that I'm going to have to deal with... =(

Comment: What happens if you open Explorer and just type in the address?

Comment: Did you try `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path)`?

Comment: @LouFranco It works properly.  The call I am using presently works properly as well.  However, this issue periodically occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bug in Windows Explorer.  Best you can do is work around it.  Does it happen on all machines or just yours?

Comment: @LouFranco Have not tested on any other machines yet.  Will try another day when one frees up.  By work around it - you mean deal with it? hahah :)

Comment: @M.Babcock Just used your code and it did nothing for about 5 mins (even in debugger), then loaded explorer and crashed it.  Definitely must be a network issue / explorer glitch.

Comment: Disable shell extensions with SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alternative way of opening the folder try using [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232.aspx). To open a folder I think you can use the same PCITEMIDLIST as the parent and the selection:

```
SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, 1, &folder, 0);
```